# Nginx TLS Passthrough (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

Tags: nginx

What I am trying do is to configure NGINX to forward https requests to corresponding containers (by hostnames) running on the same machine with TLS passthrough so TLS termination will be done at the containers. As right now, I only have bw.domain.com

Here is my nginx config that I try to config:

```
stream {
    map $ssl_preread_server_name $name {
        bw.domain.com    bw;
    }

    upstream bw {
        server  127.0.0.1:4443;
    }

    server {
        listen  443;
        proxy_pass  $name;
        ssl_preread on;
    }
}
```

Here is the nginx config generated by self-host bitwarden (upstream):

```
#######################################################################
# WARNING: This file is generated. Do not make changes to this file.  #
# They will be overwritten on update. You can manage various settings #
# used in this file from the ./bwdata/config.yml file for your        #
# installation.                                                       #
#######################################################################

server {
  listen 8080 default_server;
  listen [::]:8080 default_server;
  server_name bw.domain.com;

  return 301 https://bw.domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 8443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:8443 ssl http2;
  server_name bw.domain.com;

  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/privkey.pem;
  ssl_session_timeout 30m;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:20m;
  ssl_session_tickets off;

  # Diffie-Hellman parameter for DHE ciphersuites, recommended 2048 bits
  ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/dhparam.pem;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256";
  # Enables server-side protection from BEAST attacks
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  # OCSP Stapling ---
  # Fetch OCSP records from URL in ssl_certificate and cache them
  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;

  # Verify chain of trust of OCSP response using Root CA and Intermediate certs
  ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/ssl/fullchain.pem;
  resolver 1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1 9.9.9.9 149.112.112.112 valid=300s;

  include /etc/nginx/security-headers-ssl.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/security-headers.conf;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://web:5000/;
    include /etc/nginx/security-headers-ssl.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/security-headers.conf;
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data: https://haveibeenpwned.com https://www.gravatar.com; child-src 'self' https://*.duosecurity.com https://*.duofederal.com; frame-src 'self' https://*.duosecurity.com https://*.duofederal.com; connect-src 'self' wss://bw.domain.com https://api.pwnedpasswords.com https://2fa.directory; object-src 'self' blob:;";
    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    add_header X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow";
  }

  location /alive {
    return 200 'alive';
    add_header Content-Type text/plain;
  }

  location = /app-id.json {
    proxy_pass http://web:5000/app-id.json;
    include /etc/nginx/security-headers-ssl.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/security-headers.conf;
    proxy_hide_header Content-Type;
    add_header Content-Type $fido_content_type;
  }

  location = /duo-connector.html {
    proxy_pass http://web:5000/duo-connector.html;
  }

  location = /webauthn-connector.html {
    proxy_pass http://web:5000/webauthn-connector.html;
  }

  location = /webauthn-fallback-connector.html {
    proxy_pass http://web:5000/webauthn-fallback-connector.html;
  }

  location = /sso-connector.html {
    proxy_pass http://web:5000/sso-connector.html;
  }


  location /attachments/ {
    proxy_pass http://attachments:5000/;
  }

  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://api:5000/;
  }

  location /icons/ {
    proxy_pass http://icons:5000/;
  }

  location /notifications/ {
    proxy_pass http://notifications:5000/;
  }

  location /notifications/hub {
    proxy_pass http://notifications:5000/hub;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
  }

  location /events/ {
    proxy_pass http://events:5000/;
  }

  location /sso {
    proxy_pass http://sso:5000;
    include /etc/nginx/security-headers-ssl.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/security-headers.conf;
    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
  }

  location /identity {
    proxy_pass http://identity:5000;
    include /etc/nginx/security-headers-ssl.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/security-headers.conf;
    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
  }

  location /admin {
    proxy_pass http://admin:5000;
    include /etc/nginx/security-headers-ssl.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/security-headers.conf;
    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
  }

}
```

Right now, it throws this error when I use Firefox:

> Secure Connection Failed
>
> An error occurred during a connection to bw.domain.com.
> PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR
>
> Error code: PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR

Here is the logs of the NGINX

> 2023/01/07 23:09:37 [error] 28#28: *1 connect() failed (111:
> Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.16.1.1,
> server: 0.0.0.0:443, upstream: "127.0.0.1:4443", bytes from/to
> client:0/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/0